# What is the difference between Project, Album and Folder in Aperture 3?

Tags: software, apple-aperture

I'm sort of confused between the 3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Project:** Contains distinct photos/videos.  A given photo/video can't exist in multiple projects, if you drag a photo from a project to another project it *moves* that photo.

**Album:** Contains photos/videos from any number of projects but can only contain one instance of any photo or video.

**Folder:** Contains Projects and Albums.

So, **Project A** can contain Photo1 and Photo2 and **Project B** can contain Photo3 and Photo4.  **Album A** can contain Photo1, Photo2 and Photo3.  **Album B** can contain Photo2, Photo3, and Photo4.  **Folder A** can contain Project A and Album B.

If you drag Photo1 from Project A to Project B it becomes part of Project B and is no longer part of Project A. It has no impact on Album A and Album B.

If you make a couple test case Project, Album Folders it'll become clear :)

Comment: just went through a re-org'd last weeks stuff, think I got it now. thanks

Comment: Here's a good link which goes into more detail for what Shizam said, and explains why there are two types of folders:  http://speirs.org/blog/2008/1/8/organising-projects-and-folders-in-aperture.html